Trim function for awk
I have a trim function that I sometimes use in awk, but it's kind of slow for big inputs:
#!/bin/bash

time {
    yes $'\t   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis dapibus rutrum facilisis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam tristique libero eu nibh porttitor amet fermentum.\t    \r' |
    head -n 1000000 |
    awk '
        { trim($0) }

        function trim(string) {
            gsub(/^[ \t\r]+|[ \t\r]+$/, "", string);
            return string
        }
    '
}

real    0m9.074s
user    0m9.179s
sys     0m0.381s

How can I speed it up?

fwiw, your original code takes 1.884s and 1.241s in two of my environments, while your answer/solution is slower @ 2.093s and 1.403s; both environments are Ubuntu 22.04, bash 5.1.6, gawk 5.1.0; 1st environment is a vm (1.884s / 2.093s) while the 2nd environment is running on the physical machine (1.241s / 1.403s); cpu is an i7-1260P

It's hard to believe that this example would take over 9 seconds to run on any modern computer. On my laptop with git bash and gawk 5.0.0 it takes 2.5 seconds (and the code in the OPs answer is slower at just over 3 seconds) while on my linux desktop with gawk 4.2.1 this takes 1.7 secs while the code in the OPs answer is again slower at just over 1.9 secs. Both are running gawk

A benchmark party! Here's mine [for Q, then A] with GNU Awk 5.3.1 [1.942s, 2.173s], with mawk 1.3.4 [1.026s, 1.021s], with One True Awk 20240728 [3.859s, 12.458s], and with GoAWK v1.21.0 [8.663s, 1.010s]. Quite impressive differences! And for GoAWK, the A indeed performs better than the Q.

I guess some optimizations where implemented in the regex engine of Awk over the years; my bench's done with GNU Awk 4.1.2 on old hardware. With macOS's Awk the difference isn't so clear [6.793 vs 5.385].

Ah, yes GNU awk went through a significant speedup effort a few years ago so it could be that. Sorry, I don't recall which version had the upgrade.

@markp-fuso I'm curious - does the 2*sub()s solution run faster than the 1*gsub() for you too?

@pmf I'm curious - does the 2*sub()s solution run faster than the 1*gsub() for you too?

@Fravadona I'm curious - does the 2*sub()s solution run faster than the 1*gsub() for you too?

@EdMorton the 2sub() answer speed is negligible; repeated runs show slightly faster or slightly slower, ie, avg is roughly same as 1gsub()

@Ed My times for [2sub, 1gsub] using GNU Awk 5.3.1 [2.014 s, 1.968 s], mawk 1.3.4 [943.8 ms, 1.031 s], One True Awk 20240728 [4.020 s, 3.825 s], and GoAWK v1.21.0 [5.978 s, 8.822 s], measured with Hyperfine 1.19.0 on 10 iterations each.

@EdMorton For [Q, 2*sub, A] I get: macOS(AppleM3)[6.751s,7.010s,4.769s] LinuxGawk4.1.2(AMD5995WX):[1.436s,1.491s,1.287s] SolarisXPG4(IntelGold6146)[36.268s,24.380s,12.389s];

Thanks all - so it sounds like there's none of the current solutions is portably always faster or slower than the others. FWIW someone pointed out one time in a comment under a different Q&A on this site that a very similar gsub() solution doesn't work in ALL awks, I think it fails in mawk1 IIRC. @pmf looks like you have mawk1, would you mind adding a print and checking if mawk1 produces the same output as the other awks for the gsub() case?

@Ed My mawk comes from http://invisible-island.net/mawk/, not https://github.com/mikebrennan000/mawk-2, if this is the distinction. Nevertheless, both 2sub and 1gsub produce the same (trimmed) output.

@pmf OK, thanks. I've been trying to find the comment where someone told me about that (I think it MIGHT have been about trimming quotes with gsub(/^"|"$/,"")) rather than trimming white space but haven't been able to find it so I'm giving up. Oh well.

On my machine (Windows laptop running git bash with gawk 5.0.0) doing 2 separate sub()s seems to be very slightly faster than one gsub():
$ cat gsub.sh
#!/bin/bash

time {
    yes $'\t   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis dapibus rutrum facilisis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam tristique libero eu nibh porttitor amet fermentum.\t    \r' |
    head -n 1000000 |
    awk '
        { trim($0) }

        function trim(string) {
            gsub(/^[ \t\r]+|[ \t\r]+$/,"",string)
            return string
        }
    '
}


$ cat subs.sh
#!/bin/bash

time {
    yes $'\t   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis dapibus rutrum facilisis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam tristique libero eu nibh porttitor amet fermentum.\t    \r' |
    head -n 1000000 |
    awk '
        { trim($0) }

        function trim(string) {
            sub(/^[ \t\r]+/,"",string)
            sub(/[ \t\r]+$/,"",string)
            return string
        }
    '
}

Timing over 3 runs to remove caching impact:
    ./gsub.sh              ./subs.sh

real    0m2.288s        real    0m2.213s
user    0m2.325s        user    0m2.419s
sys     0m3.170s        sys     0m3.075s

real    0m2.269s        real    0m2.219s
user    0m2.371s        user    0m2.420s
sys     0m3.310s        sys     0m3.139s

real    0m2.275s        real    0m2.250s
user    0m2.434s        user    0m2.434s
sys     0m3.216s        sys     0m3.199s


As a rule of thumbs, regexps are generally slower than looping through the chars of a string, but depending on what you do afterwards, that may not be the case in awk. For the specific trim function you can avoid some processing by looping only through the mandatory characters at the start and at the end of the string:
#!/bin/bash

time {
    yes $'\t   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis dapibus rutrum facilisis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam tristique libero eu nibh porttitor amet fermentum.\t    \r' |
    head -n 1000000 |
    awk '
        BEGIN {
            to_trim[" "]
            to_trim["\t"]
            to_trim["\r"]
        }
        { trim($0, to_trim) }

        function trim(string,chars,    i,j) {
             i = 1
             while (substr(string,i,1) in chars) {++i}
             j = length(string)
             while (substr(string,j,1) in chars && j > i) {--j}
             return substr(string, i, j-i+1)
        }
    '
}

note: The prototype of the function was modified
real    0m1.954s
user    0m2.063s
sys 0m0.281s


You came up with your own answer in under a minute?

There's an option to "answer your own question" when asking a question. As I came up with something before finishing to write the question (I started yesterday and was interrupted), I posted both. That's only a possible solution though

Is it possible you ran this on a different computer from the original? It's hard to believe that this would run in under 2 seconds when the original took over 9 and so far every computer that others have tried both scripts on (see comments from @markp-fuso and myself under the question) have reported that the original script is faster than this one.

@Ed See my benchmarks. With GoAWK, I can replicate that the A performs better than the Q.


How can I speed it up?

Observe trimming string is so-called pure function, if it is only one operation you want to apply or your whole line transformation is done in pure manner (output does depends only at input and there are not side-effect) it make it viable target for parallel processing.
There exists parallel-awk made for that purpose, but with cave canem that it is child of One True Awk, so you MUST NOT to use GNU AWK-only features inside it.
Update: I attempted to install it at my machine, but make malfunctioned and I am unable to find relevant solution. I do not know if this is caused by my machine configuration or parallel-awk is Potemkin village rather than working software.

Even if you parallelize, making the trimming of a single line as fast as possible will still matter eventually

Here are the ultra fancy versions of it :
function trim1G(__, _) {

    if ((_ = "") + !__)
        if ((__ != (_ < _)) < (__ == _))
            return gsub(/^[ \t\r]+|[ \t\r]+$/, _)
        else
            return __
    else
        gsub(/^[ \t\r]+|[ \t\r]+$/, _, __)

    return __
}


function trim2S(__, _) {

    if ((_ = "") + !__)
        if ((__ != (_ < _)) < (__ == _))
            return sub(/^[ \t\r]+/, _) + sub(/^[ \t\r]+$/, _)
        else
            return __
    else
        sub(/^[ \t\r]+/, _, __)
        sub(/[ \t\r]+$/, _, __)

    return __
}

The performance is nearly identical between them. And mawk2 is muuuuuuch faster than every other awk I've benchmarked.
The functions can also properly differentiate between :


an actual numeric zero (e.g. trim1G(0)),
an actual empty string (e.g. trim1G("")), and
the special awk null value that is simultaneously (1) and (2) (e.g. trim1G()).


If you wanna speed up your function, consider modifying $0 in-place instead of making round-trip copies. $0 will be modified IN-PLACE only for scenario (3) for either function, with its return value being # of replacements made.
Note that calling the function as trim1G($0) / trim2S($0) DOES NOT modify $0 in-place, since a full stand-alone copy has been made.
As for benchmarking, single gsub() with mawk2 modifying $0 in-place is posting sub-second response times :
 ( time ( yes $'\t   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 
   consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis dapibus rutrum
   facilisis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad 
   litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos 
   himenaeos. Etiam tristique libero eu nibh porttitor
    amet fermentum.\t    \r' | 

ghead -n 1000000 | mawk2 '

function trim1G(__, _) {

    if ((_ = "") + !__)
        if ((__ != (_ < _)) < (__ == _))
            return gsub(/^[ \t\r]+|[ \t\r]+$/, _)
        else
            return __
    else
        gsub(/^[ \t\r]+|[ \t\r]+$/, _, __)
    return __
}
{
    trim1G() } END { print NR, NF }' ) )

 
( yes  | ghead -n 1000000 | mawk2 ; ) 

 0.90s user 0.21s system 153% cpu 0.722 total

1000000 33

